# Как в кнопке выравнить картинку и текст в одну строку?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Не понимаю куда и что писать чтобы картика и кнопка были по одной линии.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно выглядить так - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
header button {
    color: #56ce4d;
    padding: 25px 50px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 23px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.btn img {
    width: 50px;
    color: #56ce4d;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
    <header>   
       <div class="enter">
          <button class="btn"><img src=".//images/user (4).png" alt="К">Войти</button>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Правило [align-items: center](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) должно помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно прописать родителю картинки (в данном случае button) **align-items: center;**
p.s. Поменял картинку, чтобы можно было посмотреть

```css
header button {
    color: #56ce4d;
    padding: 25px 50px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 23px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
}

.btn img {
    width: 50px;
    color: #56ce4d;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header>   
       <div class="enter">
          <button class="btn"><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1250/1250689.png" alt="К">Войти</button>
        </div>
    </header>
```